# How to return a continue from a while

Tags: c++, for-loop

Hard to describe what I want to express, but I confuse for this problem very long time in my real project. My real project is too complicated to ask here, so I make a sample code like following to specify the suitation.

```
bool checkQ(int a, int b) {
    if (a < b)
        return true;
    else if (a == b)
        return false;
    else/*This is last else.*/
    {
        cout << "I cannot process a even number." << endl;
        return false;
    }
}

vector<int> fun(vector<int> vec) {
    vector<int> result;
    int die = 29;
    for (int i : vec) {
        do {
            i+=2;
            result.push_back(i);
        } while (checkQ(i,die));
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> loop_times{1,2,3};
    vector<vector<int>> vec_result;
    for/*his is outer for*/ (int i : loop_times) {
        vector<int> vec{ 23,25,26,25 };
        vector<int> tem_vec = fun(vec);
        vec_result.push_back(tem_vec);
    }

    for (vector<int> j : vec_result)
    {
        for (int k : j)
            cout << k << "  ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output of the sample code

> ```
> I cannot process a even number.
> I cannot process a even number.
> I cannot process a even number.
>
> 25  27  29  27  29  28  30  27  29
>
> 25  27  29  27  29  28  30  27  29
>
> 25  27  29  27  29  28  30  27  29
> ```

As you see, my function `fun` cannot to process a even element. I just can return a `false` to stop process the `30`. But actually I hope to return a `continue` for the **outer for** in `fun`. I just don't know how to implement such programe. I think I can change the `return false;` into a `goto` function **`checkQ`** to do it like

```
bool checkQ(int a, int b) {
    if (a < b)
        return true;
    else if (a == b)
        return false;
    else/*This is last else.*/
    {
        cout << "I cannot process a even number." << endl;
        goto tag;
    }
}

vector<int> fun(vector<int> vec) {
    vector<int> result;
    int die = 29;
    for (int i : vec) {
        do {
            i+=2;
            result.push_back(i);
        } while (checkQ(i,die));
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> loop_times{1,2,3};
    vector<vector<int>> vec_result;
    for/*his is outer for*/ (int i : loop_times) {
        vector<int> vec{ 23,25,26,25 };
        vector<int> tem_vec = fun(vec);
        vec_result.push_back(tem_vec);
    tag:continue;
    }

    for (vector<int> j : vec_result)
    {
        for (int k : j)
            cout << k << "  ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you see, I make many grammar error in above code. Any way, I hope the actually output is

> ```
> I cannot process a even number.
> I cannot process a even number.
> I cannot process a even number.
>
> 25  27  29  27  29  28  30
>
> 25  27  29  27  29  28  30
>
> 25  27  29  27  29  28  30
> ```

Anybody can help me out?

Comment: Upvoted for providing input, desired output vs. actual output, and a sample program as a minimal working example. I wish other new-comers would read this questions first. It is a sign of respect to the readers, and makes it likely to receive a helpful answer, too.

Comment: You did not specified the c++ standard version, but `std::optional` or `std::variant` could help you at this point. (there might be also available in boost if it counts). They not solve the problem entirely, but may help, or their main idea can be used for insiration (:
I would not recommend exceptions because this case is part of the normal control flow and not exceptional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the result of `checkQ`, there are **three** different actions, but you only provide **two** return value.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

enum CHECKQ_RC {
    GOOD,
    OK,
    NEED_TO_QUIT
};

CHECKQ_RC checkQ(int a, int b) {
    if (a < b)
        return GOOD;
    else if (a == b)
        return OK;
    else/*This is last else.*/
    {
        cout << "I cannot process a even number." << endl;
        return NEED_TO_QUIT;
    }
}

vector<int> fun(vector<int> vec) {
    vector<int> result;
    int die = 29;
    for (int i : vec) {
        int j;
        do {
            i+=2;
            result.push_back(i);
            j = checkQ(i, die);
            if (GOOD != j) break;
        } while (true);
        if (j == NEED_TO_QUIT) break;
    }

    return result;
}


int main()
{
    vector<int> loop_times{1,2,3};
    vector<vector<int>> vec_result;
    for/*his is outer for*/ (int i : loop_times) {
        vector<int> vec{ 23,25,26,25 };
        vector<int> tem_vec = fun(vec);
        vec_result.push_back(tem_vec);
    }

    for (vector<int> j : vec_result)
    {
        for (int k : j)
            cout << k << "  ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
// without checkQ
vector<int> fun(vector<int> vec) {
    vector<int> result;
    int die = 29;
    for (int i : vec) {
        do {
            i+=2;
            result.push_back(i);
        } while (i < die);
        if (i > die) break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You are a crazy man :). It confuse me so many days, but you answer it just several minute..(message form [user tem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9197066/tem))

Comment: Bye the way, could I don't build  that judge function `checkQ` but use a `if` directly in that `while`?

Comment: @yode sure, of course. just code your thought and check

Comment: Sure? Can you help to implement it without that `checkQ`? I really don't know how to do it..When I use `if` directly, the vs reminder me there need a expression(`if` is not a expression obviously)..

Comment: @yode you should really try coding first. write whatever across in your mind. you can check my updates if need some hint.

Answer (score 1):

Encountering an even number in `checkQ` is an exceptional condition and for this i would use an exception. This allows you choose on which level you want to handle the problem without introducing additional return values and passing them around until you reach the location where the problem is handled.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct EvenNumberException
{
};

bool checkQ(int a, int b)
{
  if (a < b)
    return true;
  else if (a == b)
    return false;
  else /*This is last else.*/
  {
    throw EvenNumberException{};
  }
}

vector<int> fun(vector<int> vec)
{
  vector<int> result;
  int die = 29;
  try
  {
    for (int i : vec)
    {
      do
      {
        i += 2;
        result.push_back(i);
      } while (checkQ(i, die));
    }
  }
  catch (EvenNumberException)
  {
    /* no cleanup necessary */
  }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  vector<int> loop_times{ 1, 2, 3 };
  vector<vector<int> > vec_result;
    for/*his is outer for*/ (int i : loop_times)
    {
      vector<int> vec{ 23, 25, 26, 25 };
      vector<int> tem_vec = fun(vec);
      vec_result.push_back(tem_vec);
    }

    for (vector<int> j : vec_result)
    {
      for (int k : j)
        cout << k << "  ";
      cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```